# New colors for highlighting text in mac preview

Tags: macos, colors, highlight, preview

There are only 5 colors in mac preview to highlight your text.
Does anyone know any way to add more colors to this? or at least to change a couple of them.
These colors are too dark for me for highlighting!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**There is a way, but it may be a little more troublesome.**

1. You can click on the icon located on the top right of the preview
   window that looks like a briefcase. A toolbar will pop up.
2. Click on
   the 3rd icon in the new toolbar. It auto-straightens your drawn line
   if it is pretty straight.
3. Colour options are the in the third last
   icon. There are many many options. To make it semi-transparent like a highlight, just need to click "Show colors" and adjust the "Opacity" slider in the Color window.
4. Lastly, the thickness of the line
   as a highlight can be controlled in the fourth-last icon.

**Speed tips:**

1. To make it faster to highlight multiple lines, you can click your
   first highlight, Control-C to copy it, then Control-V to paste it.
   This eliminates the need to redraw every time. Just need to move it
   to your next highlighting line.
2. If you have a whole block that
   you need to highlight, you can copy a previous block, say of 3
   lines, and paste it, then drag it to the new area. To do this, you
   just have to select the first highlight, press and hold the Shift
   key, and select the next 2 highlights. Then Control-C and Control-V
   as before.
3. If you're highlighting a block for the first time, you can draw or move a previously copied highlight on to the last line of your block. Then, once you copy your new highlight, pasting it each time subsequently will automatically paste it one line higher than the previous. For this to work, you will have to copy right after you paste your new line.
   (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, etc.)

**Note for pasting in a different page:**

After you Control-C the highlight(s), click on the new page, and then Control-V.